# ASP.NET Core async Task<IList<MyObject>> Cannot be used in 'foreach'

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1

I have been trying to get my head around async in asp.net core 3.0, but I am still missing something.

I have some async db queries:

```
public async Task<IList<MyObject>> GetAll(MyContext context)    
{        
    var a = MyMethodA(context);    
    var b = MyMethodA(context);    
    return (await Task.WhenAll(a, b)).SelectMany(e => e).ToList();
}
```

index.cs:

```
public Task<IList<MyObject>> MyDBList  { get; set; }

public void OnGet()
{
    MyDBList = _myInterface.GetAll(context);
}
```

Index.cshml

```
foreach (var x in Model.MyDBList) {
    <p>x.ID</p>
}
```

On index.cshtml I get the error System.Threading.Tasks.Task> cannot be used in 'foreach' statement because it neither implements 'IEnumerable' or 'IEnumerable', nor has suitable 'GetEnumerator'

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to use an await on your call to your async function - like so:

```
public void OnGet() 
    MyDBList = await _myInterface.GetAll(context);
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I was getting an error there because I am not using OnGetAsync and I misunderstood what the error was saying.